# Protobuf Doubles Serializing as Null Bytes

Tags: java, serialization, double, protocol-buffers

I have created a very simple java class using Google Protobuf 2.6.1, with the following structure:

```
required int64 tid = 1;
required int64 tid = 1;
required string clOrdID = 2;
required string execID = 3;
required string ticketType = 4;
optional string lastMkt = 5;
required double lastQty = 6;
required double cumQty = 7;
required double lastPx = 8;
required double avgPx = 9;
optional string lastCapacity = 10;
required int64 transactionTime = 11;
required int64 reportTime = 12;
```

After building the class and populating these fields with test data, I am converting it to a byte array using the .toByteArray() method:

```
double d = 99.0;
FillProto fillProto = FillProto.newBuilder()
                        .setTid(n)
                        .setClOrdID("ClOrdID")
                        .setExecID("ExecID")
                        .setTicketType("ticketType")
                        .setLastMkt("LastMkt")
                        .setLastQty(d)
                        .setCumQty(d)
                        .setLastPx(d)
                        .setAvgPx(d)
                        .setLastCapacity("LastCapacity")
                        .setTransactionTime(now.getTime())
                        .setReportTime(now.getTime())
                        .build();

Log.info(class_,method_,"Sending through:\n" + new String(fillProto.toByteArray()));
```

I am sending the ByteArray through a Solace queue, and after consuming on the other side, I try to build another object using FillProto.parseFrom(byte[]) but get an error: "While parsing a protocol message, the input ended unexpectedly in the middle of a field.". The ByteArray seems to look fine, up until the fields marked as double, which are all outputting as null (00 bytes). Does anyone know what's happening here?

Byte Array below:

```
  08 05 12 07 63 6c 4f 72    64 49 44 1a 06 65 78 65    ....clOrdID..exe
  63 49 44 22 0a 74 69 63    6b 65 74 54 79 70 65 2a    cID".ticketType*
  07 6c 61 73 74 4d 6b 74    31 00 00 00 00 00 c0 58    .lastMkt1......X
  40 39 00 00 00 00 00 c0    58 40 41 00 00 00 00 00    @9......X@A.....
  c0 58 40 49 00 00 00 00    00 c0 58 40 52 0c 4c 61    .X@I......X@R.La
  73 74 43 61 70 61 63 69    74 79 58 b0 8b a8 ce e6    stCapacityX.....
  29 60 b0 8b a8 ce e6 29                               )`.....)
```

Comment: `new String(fillProto.toByteArray())` can be expected to do horrible things.  Don't just dump a random proto into a `String` like that, use an encoding of some kind.  Other than that -- `99.0` does have many zero bits in its IEEE 754 binary representation.  Could that be it?

Comment: Agree with Louis. Do you have any evidence that this encoding isn't correct?

Comment: I'm passing the byte array through a Solace Queue as a Byte Message. When I consume it on the other end and attempt to create another FillProto object use FillProto.parseFrom(byte[]), I'm getting an error that the input ended unexpectedly in the middle of a field. From reading another thread it seemed like this might be caused by the nulls sitting in the byte array (which is being output with msg.dump). Other proto objects that I am passing through this queue which do not have any doubles are re-building fine on the other side.

Comment: Nevermind, turns out I was not using .parseFrom(byte[]) for that particular proto. I had an if statement separating the code into different paths depending on the data type retrieved, and that particular block hadn't been updated from an old approach. Completely user error.

Answer (score 4):

This is normal. Doubles are represented using the standard 8-byte IEEE-754 representation. The double value zero is represented as all zeros, and most other values will contain zeros as well.

It sounds like your messaging infrastructure is designed to operate on NUL-terminated text strings. Such infrastructure will not work with raw Protobuf content, because it will truncate the message at the first NUL byte. In general, you cannot use raw Protobuf data in a context designed for text, as various corruption will likely occur. Note in particular that you should never pass protobuf bytes to `new String()`, because `String` stores Unicode text, not bytes.

If you need to transmit Protobufs where text is expected, you will need to base64-encode your data to prevent such corruption -- base64 allows raw bytes to be placed in a textual context, but increases the overall size of the data by 33%.